# Returning values from a list of strings that are unknown

Tags: python, string, return

I need to write two programs that return the word with the most punctuation from a string. There is also a program that I need to remove all punctuation from a different string.

for the first one I tried this.

```
total = 0
number = 0
for c in words:
    if c.isdigit():
        number += int(c)
        if number > total:
            total = number
            

return total
```

second one I tried

```
result = ''
for char in string:
    if char.isdigit():
        result += '*'
    else:
        result += char
return result
```

Comment: There is a `return` so I'm assuming this is a function definition?

Comment: Punctuation means dot, comma, period, etc., right? So why do you call isdigit, which returns if it is a digit (0..9)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sum()` function along with a generator that tests each character in the word.

I'm treating any character that isn't alphanumeric as punctuation. Assuming you've already split the input into words, there shouldn't be any whitespace that would confuse this.

```
def count_punc(word):
    return sum(not char.isalnum() for char in word)
```